# Bundle two apps in one codfile

Tags: browser, blackberry

I'm creating an app in which I want to hide a part of app and want to show another part.

If I do this with two different cod files installed on phone. Than I know this is possible. But is it possible to combined both files in one  package and at the time of installation both should be installed in one step?

Practically I think this is not possible, but I am asking for the advice of experts.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to achieve what you want using a single app with multiple entry points. See the information here:

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/AppLifecycle-summary.html

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/796557/800738/800901/How_To_-_Setup_an_alternate_entry_point_for_my_application.html?nodeid=800820

Not knowing anything about your apps, it's hard to say exactly what you need.

Note that you can package multiple apps into the same JAD for installation/uninstallation as a single unit. Maybe that's all you need.

Comment: +1 I think "multiple apps into the same JAD" is probably what he wants

Answer (score 1):

You may bundle multiple cod files for over the air installation, but not multiple applications into one cod file afaik.

For example you can use this approach to bundle the RIM advertising cod.

Add the cod file and its size to the jad file, e.g.

```
RIM-COD-URL-1: foo.cod
RIM-COD-Size-1: 40000
```

Above I've used RIM-COD-URL-1, but you may need to use RIM-COD-URL-2, -3 etc, take the next number depending on the entries you already have for your existing cod's.

If you are uploading to the RIM app store you just need to provide all of the cod files as they don't require the JAD file.